# Get current file name after include in PHP

Tags: php, include

Let's pretend I have the following
**class.wrapper.php**

```
// loop through events/ directory ($eventFile = filename of parsed file)
include $eventFile;
```

**myevent.php**

```
echo __FILE__;
```

**myotherevent.php**

```
echo __FILE__;
```

Both of the echo return the same thing: **class.wrapper.php**, is there a way to get the real file name ? not the one which included the code ?

The **class.wrapper** is part of an encrypted API which allows user to define custom php files in a given directory to invoke user defined code when a given event is fired in the main application, so I cannot edit the main class, I have to do this only by editing "events" files

Comment: Strange. According to the documentation on http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php the __FILE__ magic constant should return the name of the included file.

Comment: that's what I thought too, the problem is that I'm using third party code (encrypted) which allows me to fill thoses 'events' php files to execute third party code when they are fired, so I don't know exactly if they're using include, but seems the most logic thing to do

Answer (score 1):

Try the below function

```
function GetInclude($file, $params = array())
    {
        extract($params);
        include $file;
    }
    myevent.php
    <?php GetInclude('class.wrapper.php', array('includerFile' => __FILE__)); ?>
    myotherevent.php
    <?php GetInclude('class.wrapper.php', array('includerFile' => __FILE__)); ?>
    class.wrapper.php
    echo $includerFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the real name, which is for your example the complete path to access this file, use the function `realpath("yourfile.extension")`.

I let you with this short example :

Let's say I have a file named index.php. I want to display its complete path. Here is the code to do so :

```
<?php
    echo realpath("index.php");
?>
```

In my example, I saved my file in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php. The result will be a display of this exact path.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I cannot edit the wrapper class, it's an API encrypted that dinamically include some files in a given directory

Comment: From which API this comes from ? does it have any docs ? Let me know this in order to try finding some function like this above.

Comment: I don't think the light doc will help you, but here it is  https://dev.hostbillapp.com/events-hooks

Comment: Quite difficult in fact to know in which event I need to search for.. But if I correctly understood, your filename is included in you $eventFile var. Even echo realpath($eventFile) returns "class.wrapper.php" ? In any case I need to know your event if you want me to make my research easier

Comment: The only thing available to me, it's an (many) empty php file. This file is included when an event is fired, I don't mind when this occurs. In this file, I want to find the file name, using __FILE__ doesn't work (returns the name of class file which included the current file)